# list 6 previous month names from current date MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

My aim is to list 6 previous month names from current date,using MySQL;
i am able to find particular `monthNAme` before certain months using the following query

```
MySQL= "SELECT MONTHNAME((now() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) as Previous_month FROM"
       " search.search_option where file_no='1'"
```

But how can i list 6 previous `monthNames`.

Comment: You want to generate last 6 month names (from dual) or you want to group the data based on last 6 months ?

Comment: no need to extract any data, only want to display the month names

Comment: You said you want it from current date then why you are using LAST_DAY() in your query ?

Comment: i need 6 previous months, that's why

Comment: You can use NOW() only. No need of LAST_DAY() I guess.

Comment: So you want all these 6 month names in a single column or in multiple ?

Comment: @  Rishi Vedpathak : thanks i update the question, i want to display 6 previous month name in a single column titled `Previous_month`

Comment: If you want result in single column and multiple rows use ans1 by and if in single column and single row use ans2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why do you need to do this in MySQL, but here is one of possible options:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(now())
UNION
SELECT MONTHNAME(now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
UNION
SELECT MONTHNAME(now() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
UNION
SELECT MONTHNAME(now() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
UNION
SELECT MONTHNAME(now() - INTERVAL 4 MONTH)
UNION
SELECT MONTHNAME(now() - INTERVAL 5 MONTH)
```

Comment: @RishiVedpathak Because in your case output will be in single row. But OP want single column

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTHNAME(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MONTH),',',
   MONTHNAME(NOW() - INTERVAL 4 MONTH),',',       
   MONTHNAME(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH),',',
   MONTHNAME(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH),',',
   MONTHNAME(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH),',',
   MONTHNAME(NOW())) AS Previous_month;
```

Comment: i want to display 6 previous month name in a single column titled Previous_month, this produces multiple columns, so union is needed

Comment: Ohh I've updated my answer. Use concat instead of union.